Ubuntu installer not working for legacy
Yeah, so im trying to install Ubuntu for my legacy bios device, but Ubuntu forcefully tries to install in uefi, even after i changed the boot settings to bios in rufus its the same issue. And i tried to delete the "EFI" folder in the usb itself, the bootloader loads successfully but when i actually enter on install ubuntu it says "452: out of range pointer: 0xbafff010
Aborted: Press any key to return". PLEASE I GENUINELY NEED HELP THIS IS IMPORTANT

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Your provided details imply a user-created issue; use the documented write procedure for the ISO and it will install to BIOS, uEFI and Secure-uEFI devices. The only complications can be hardware specific (ie. 64-bit device but with 32-bit uEFI) but that doesn't apply to legacy devices.  You've provided no hardware specifics & details imply a reformatted ISO write (which is expected to not work on all devices!)
